# SQL hide rows specifically

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure and sample rows:

[image: Table and inserted rows]

And I have a SQL query like this :

```
WITH Test(ObjId, ObjectIcerik, KeyMi) AS
(
    SELECT 
        ObjId, ObjectIcerik, KeyMi 
    FROM 
        Tek
    WHERE 
        ObjId = 8

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        T.ObjId, T.ObjectIcerik, T.KeyMi 
    FROM 
        Tek T 
    INNER JOIN 
        Test as TE ON T.ObjParent = TE.ObjId
)
SELECT * 
FROM Test
```

This is the result :

[image: SQL query result]

But I also need to hide parent and child rows if parent's `KeyMi` column is '1'.

What do I need to change in the SQL query to do this?

Comment: I don't know what "hiding" means in this context.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results as text *in the question*.  You can prepend four spaces to each line to get a better formatted table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your suggestions. But I don't have a reputation for embed images.

Comment: @bouteillebleu Thanks for edit.

Comment: What happened to Uzun Tossu Tisort?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's not important. The important point is Key. If the "KeyMi" column is '1' I need to hide this row and row's child rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add the condition to the recursive CTE:

```
WITH Test(ObjId, ObjectIcerik, KeyMi) AS (
    SELECT ObjId, ObjectIcerik, KeyMi FROM Tek
    WHERE ObjId = 8 AND (KeyMI <> 1 OR KeyMI IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.ObjId, T.ObjectIcerik, T.KeyMi
    FROM Tek T INNER JOIN
         Test TE
         ON T.ObjParent = TE.ObjId
    WHERE (t.KeyMI <> 1 OR t.KeyMI IS NULL)
)   
SELECT *
FROM Test ;
```

Comment: @ÖmürCanYurdugül . . . Is there a reason you accepted and then unaccepted the answer?